# Tried logging to auth0 i got invalid state error

Tags: auth0

I have a problem with auth0.

There are two auth0 Applications in the project that I am working on right now. One is in PHP other one is WordPress. Both use auth0 Hosted Page.

First I opened my WordPress site in a tab in my web browser. Then I opened the same in another tab. Then tried logging in from the first tab by entering the email and the password and got the below error message:

> [wordpress error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbUV.jpg) "There was a problem with your log in:
>   Invalid state [error code: unknown]"

If it is a PHP site got the below error message:

> [php error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWNsl.jpg) "Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Auth0\SDK\Exception\CoreException: Invalid state in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uat.sso\sso\vendor\auth0\auth0-php\src\Auth0.php:511
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uat.sso\sso\vendor\auth0\auth0-php\src\Auth0.php(434):
>   Auth0\SDK\Auth0->exchange() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uat.sso\sso\callback.php(8):
>   Auth0\SDK\Auth0->getUser() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uat.sso\sso\vendor\auth0\auth0-php\src\Auth0.php on
>   line 511"

Comment: Hi Ishan, welcome to SO. Could you please just write the error messages here (as qouted text) instead of images? The images can become unavailable with time and it would greatly improve readability.

Comment: Thanks, hakamairi, I have put it as a text.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 have a comprehensive guide on dealing with Invalid State errors in WordPress. You can check it out [here](https://auth0.com/docs/cms/wordpress/invalid-state).

Basically the most common causes are:

- Cached Auth0 Callback URL, some hosting provider do this by default and they should be contacted to not cache this.
- Cached Cookies and URL parameters
- Cookie name requirements for certain hosting providers like Pantheon.

See the complete list [here](https://auth0.com/docs/cms/wordpress/invalid-state#common-causes-of-the-invalid-state-error).